# How to store (and use) the current mouse position?

Tags: cocoa, events, mouse, macos-carbon, nsevent

What is the best way to store the current mouse position (system-wide) and then (later) put the mouse at that stored point?

[`[NSEvent mouseLocation]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/mouseLocation) gets me the position, and I can move the mouse with a [`CGEventMouseMoved`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-BBCFCJGH), but they each use a different co-ordinates system (I believe y=0 is the top for NSEvent and the bottom for a CGEvent).

I'm worried about the robustness of capturing the screen height and using it to convert between the two - or is this the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the main screen's height is the standard way of flipping screen coordinates.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I get the user's screen resolution in order to flip the y axis?

Comment: Yes, see the various methods of `NSScreen`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [CGEventTap](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/) to get the mouse events instead of NSEvent. Then you have your choice of flipped or unflipped at the time the event arrives.

> (I believe y=0 is the top for NSEvent and the bottom for a CGEvent).

You have that the wrong way around. Quartz uses flipped, which is y=0=top. AppKit uses unflipped, which is y=0=bottom. (Edit: For events, that is. Quartz 2D, the drawing API, uses unflipped coordinates, the same as AppKit does.)

Comment: But doesn't a tap just capture events?  Maybe I understand it wrong.  The mouse may be stationary (in fact likely will be) when I want to snap it to a new position and back again.  The need to do this is not determined by another keyboard or mouse event, but something that happens periodically.

Comment: Oh, so you're not monitoring events, but just getting and saving the mouse location at a specific time? Never mind about the tap, then. The part about the origins stands, though.